# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener on a null object reference even I define all the buttons

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

```
package cppandi.apjquotes;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.CountDownTimer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
Button btn1;
Button btn2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.front);
btn1 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.quotes);
btn2 = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.about);
new CountDownTimer(5000, 1000) {

@Override
public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
}

@Override
public void onFinish() {
//set the new Content of your activity
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
}.start();
btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { 
public void onClick(View v) {
// Perform action on click
Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), quotes.class);
startActivity(i);
}
});
btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
public void onClick(View v) {
// Perform action on click
Intent i = new Intent(v.getContext(), about.class);
startActivity(i);
}
});
}}





<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="cppandi.apjquotes.MainActivity">

<Button
android:text="@string/quotes"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_marginTop="126dp"
android:id="@+id/quotes"
android:onClick="btnClickAct1"/>
<Button
android:text="@string/about"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_below="@+id/quotes"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/quotes"
android:layout_alignStart="@+id/quotes"
android:layout_marginTop="94dp"
android:id="@+id/about"
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/quotes"
android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/quotes"
android:onClick="btnClickAct2"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here I am getting the error of "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference"  Even I have defiend all the buttons.

Comment: A timer is asynchronous. The rest of the code will execute before the timer finishes and sets your layout. If you want to stick to this approach, assign and set buttons inside the timer finish after setting the layout.

Comment: And Please use proper indentation when asking questions it is easier for everybody.

Comment: Okay, I have indented properly but question is not posted, it is asking to give 4 spaces indent for each line.

Answer (score 0):

Your buttons are in the layout_main.

You are setting the main layout after 5 seconds. At the point and this point only will the layout be inflated and set.

If you try to reference views before that point, the views will return null. Your buttons and listeners should be assigned only after the timer finishes. Until then, even if you use the findViewById, the views will be assigned null since the layout isn't inflated.

Changing layouts like this using a timer is probably not a good idea in the first place. I think your are looking for a splash screen instead of the current approach. Google splash screen to show when the app hasn't yet loaded.

Comment: Without timeout condition, Can I set up one image for 3-4 seconds when app get started.  If so please give one example.

Comment: Google splash screen buddy. That's exactly what A splash screen does. Then you should only set the main layout without a timer.